# Java client block server application

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, blocking

I have a client-server application.
I send some information by client, server read this information, do a operation and send result to client.

When i wait to have result in client, its blocking my server application. Server receives information but don't excecute my application...
If i don't wait a result in my client, my server excecute my application but ... I'dont have result for my client.

ps: It's for a homework, i know it's better to use rmi for this in a normal case.

Here my client code:

```
public static void transfertFile(BufferedReader in,Socket so,long sizeFile) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader buffRes;
    buffRes = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(so.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter printOut;      
    printOut = new PrintWriter(so.getOutputStream());
    String taille = String.valueOf(sizeFile);
    printOut.println(taille);
    printOut.flush();
    printOut.println("client.Calc");
    printOut.flush();
    printOut.println("add");
    printOut.flush();
    printOut.println("10");
    printOut.flush();
    printOut.println("2");
    printOut.flush();
    String str;
    int n;
    String line;
    System.out.println("file=>"+ "\n\n");
    System.out.println("Sending file...");
    while((line = in.readLine())!= null){
         str = line;
         System.out.println(str);
         printOut.println(str);
         printOut.flush();
    }
    in.close();
    String res="";
    res = buffRes.readLine();
    System.out.println("res:"+res);
}
```

Now my first function in server (just receive my file and information to excecute):

```
public static String[] transfert(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //reception des params et de la class
        buffIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String size = buffIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("size:"+size);
        String nomClasse = buffIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("Name class:" + nomClasse + " !");
        String methode = buffIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("Method :" + methode + " !");
        String param1 = buffIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("Parameter 1 :" + param1 + " !");
        String param2 = buffIn.readLine();
        System.out.println("Parameter 2:" + param2 + " !");
        String fileReadLine ="";
        String file ="";
        while((fileReadLine = buffIn.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(fileReadLine);
            file += fileReadLine;
        }

        System.out.println("file :" + file + " !");
 //       byte buff[] = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(file);
        byte[] buff = file.getBytes();
        out.write(buff);
        out.close();
        out.flush();
        //Tableau qui contient les valeurs à connaitre pour excevuter la classe
        String param[] = new String[4];
        param[0] = nomClasse;
        param[1] = methode;
        param[2] = param1;
        param[3] = param2;
        return param;
    }
```

And my 2nd function who excecute a method and send result to client:

```
public void reflexion(String[] param, OutputStream out) {
        String className = param[0];
        Class saClass;
        try {
            saClass = Class.forName(className);
            try {
                Object obj = saClass.newInstance();
                try {
                    Method m = saClass.getMethod(param[1], int.class, int.class);
                    int res;
                    try {
                        Object[] args = {Integer.parseInt(param[2]), Integer.parseInt(param[3])};
                        res = (int) m.invoke(obj, args);
                        String taille = Integer.toString(res);
                        taille = "Le resultat du calcul est:"+res+"\r";
                        System.out.println(taille);
                        System.out.println("Envoie du resultat...");
                        PrintWriter printOut;
                        printOut = new PrintWriter(out);
                        printOut.flush();
                        printOut.checkError();
                        printOut.print(taille);
                        printOut.flush();
                        printOut.close();
                        System.out.println("fin");
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AcceptClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AcceptClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AcceptClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(AcceptClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AcceptClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AcceptClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AcceptClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }
```

Comment: Usually, when a connection is stablished, your server should spawn a different thread and process the connection in that thread. In the main thread, the server puts itself to listen again at the port.

Comment: It's a multi thread server. Im not sure to understand what you are saying.
I should have a thread for input and a thread for outout ?

Comment: Get rid of all those flush() calls except the last one in each case. You are driving TCP/IP mad. You should really only flush at the end of the request or response.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decide to close my socket, and open it again after to send result to my client.
It doesn't block my serv app, and I can receive result.